# LNK2005 error solved by defining in .cpp instead of header. Why?

Tags: c++

So I had a function that was intended to read from a file. It was declared and defined in FileIO.h, like so:

```
std::string ReadFromFile(std::ifstream& in)
{
    std::string out;
    in >> out;
    return out;
}
```

Now, I included this header into another header, which was itself included into another header, which was included into main. Even though it wasn't included into multiple things, I have the `#ifndef-#def-#endif` preprocessors on all my header files, with unique names.

I couldn't for the life of me figure out why it was still throwing the linker error (in fact, it was throwing it twice: once in my Main, and once in the second header file). Then I tried simply declaring the function in FileIO.h, like this:

```
std::string ReadFromFile(std::ifstream& in);
```

Then I defined it in FileIO.cpp. No more linker errors! Is this because I was defining variables in the function, and they were being compiled and then seen later (like `std::string out`, for example), or is it from something else? I'd love a good lesson on why this worked. Thanks!

Comment: `ReadFromFile` was compiled in separately in more than one translation unit. Each by itself will compile fine, but come link-time the result object code from each individual compile is stitched together and multiple occurrences are finally discovered (first by the linker, and shortly thereafter, *by you*).

Comment: Thanks very much! This makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably puzzled by the fact that your include guards did not appear to work. Here's the missing piece of the puzzle:

The compiler processes your code in terms of individual *translation units*. That  is just a fancy term for "one .cpp file and the set of headers that it directly or indirectly includes" -- the important thing is that each TU is compiled independently of all the others.

When the compiler processes e.g. `main.cpp` it eventually sees your header and includes a compiled `ReadFromFile` in the resulting `main.obj`. If that was the only TU in your project then it would not make any difference where exactly you implemented `ReadFromFile`.

However if you have another TU, e.g. `stuff.cpp` that also eventually pulls in the header defining `ReadFromFile` then you have a problem: that function ends up being present in both `main.obj` and `stuff.obj`, which makes the linker complain because now you end up violating the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).

Note that inside each individual TU your include guards work as intended: the *compiler* does not complain while processing each one no matter how many times you try to pull in the same header.

Comment: Beautiful explanation, and you're right, I was totally confused at first that the guards did not work, but I have to remind myself that that's not their primary purpose, eh? Thanks!

Comment: @Lapys: The include guards are there for the compiler, and they operate inside a CU. The linker however then has to link the object code from all CUs into one executable image, and that's a brand new opportunity for duplicates to occur.

Answer (score 0):

You got a linker error because the same function was implemented in multiple object files, because it was implemented in the header file.

You could've avoided it by using `static inline` in front of the function.

Comment: Just `inline` would do.

Comment: Awesome explanation! Thanks! Just for argument's sake: if I had done the same thing, but I had only included the header within Main and nowhere else, would it have still thrown the linker error?

Comment: @Lapys No. Remember that #include works as if you copy-pasted the whole header file into the source file. That's why #including a function definition in two source files gives you multiple definition errors (because it's as if you copy-pasted it into both source files).